# Script to export data from Word to Excel

Tags: python, excel, powershell, ms-word, export

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I really don't have a clue how to solve this task.

I was asked to write/find a script that would go through folders with Word documents, take some data from them (for example second line in every word doc) and export them to prepaired columns in one common Excel sheet.

All the folders with Word documents are on a SharePoint site. I was not told the technology to be used to realize this, I guess there are two main options: Python or powershell.

Down below I put two pics, this is how it should approximately look like. Please, if anyone has got any thoughts, ideas or tips, it will be highly appreciated.

Example of a target file:

[image: example target file]

Example of a source file:

[image: example source file]

Answer (score 0):

You can always start by finding the API for SharePoint, which is located here:

https://github.com/ox-it/python-sharepoint

Learn to connect using your desired auth method, and then go from there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look